# Webmaster Tools - Preferred Domain and Google entries

Tags: seo, google-search-console, google-search, duplicate-content

Our client has two websites with the same content:

- `example.com`
- `somethingelse.com`

When a user searches in Google for "something else" the `example.com` site appears in the top 10 results on Google. What would happen if we switched the preferred domain in webmaster tools to `somethingelse.com`? Our client is hoping it will replace the "`example.com`" result with "`somethingelse.com`" but I assume this is not the case.

Comment: Where do you set this "preferred domain" in GWT? In GWT the "preferred domain" option is for selecting either the www or non-www version of your site, nothing more.

Comment: @w3d this was information from our client so perhaps it is not possible anyway. Thanks for the heads up.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is no point having [two websites with the same content and the same TLD](http://www.seomoz.org/blog/new-info-from-google-and-yahoo-tilts-the-geotargeting-balance). One is going to be seen as a duplicate of the other and Google is not going to list both in the SERPs. The domain name is only a small metric that Google uses in order to determine relevance in the results.

You are better of, either:

- Concentrate on one domain. Pick one domain and redirect the other domain to it using a 301 redirect in .htaccess.
  (As stated in comments, I don't believe you can set the "preferred domain" in the way you mention, in GWT. The preferred domain in GWT merely selects between the www and bare domain - this is better off done with a 301 redirect in .htaccess anyway.)

Or

- Write entirely new, different content on the other domain.